# raspberry pi fails to get IP - Repeater setup

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, repeater

I have a wifi Repeater setup. The host AP is around 25m away in another house, nothing in between but the two external walls.

In my house, I am running a TL-WA901ND as repeater. It actually all works pretty well - BUT for my raspberry pi (1B, 512).

All my devices (2 linux, 2 Win, 2 Androids) connect flawlessly to the local Repeater. But my raspberry pi with wireless dongle won't. It would get a 169.254.x.x IP address and simply not connect properly. I was speculating it could be some timeout issue, due to the Repeater setup, where the remote AP is actually the DHCP server.

I managed to verify that the dongle is recognized and working well by setting up one of the Androids as hotspot. The Pi got a WiFi connection quickly. So I guess it must be my WiFi setup with the Repeater.

Any suggestion on how I could solve my problem here?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using WDS between the repeater and the access point it's repeating? If not, expect pain and trouble.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it's setup as UniversalRepeater. What are prerequisites to be able to use WDS?

Comment: My investigations: - compatible WDS implementations, and admin access to both routers. I have the latter, need to check on the former

Comment: WDS will be much more reliable than fake relaying using MAC NAT. You want WDS if you possibly can get it.