# TP-Link WA901ND: Can it be setup as a repeater AND local SSID with DHCP?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, repeater

This question follows from 
[raspberry pi fails to get IP - Repeater setup](https://superuser.com/questions/1208419/raspberry-pi-fails-to-get-ip-repeater-setup)

which I asked myself but hasn't any suggestion (answer) yet. So trying to find a solution myself:

I have a repeater, which is connected to an AP 25m away in another house. DHCP is running on the remote AP. All works fine but for my RaspberryPi (check above question).

Can I setup my repeater to work as repeater for the remote network AND create a local SSID, with local DHCP? I know the TP-Link WA901ND has several modes of operation, but I guess this is not possible. Maybe "bridge" mode could do this? Do I loose signal strength locally or something if I run the repeater in Bridge mode?

Comment: You're probably barking up the wrong tree. If you statically configure an IP address into the RPi, does it work? I'll be the answer is no, and if so your focus on DHCP is unjustified and leading you in totally the wrong direction.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz correct, it doesn't work if I change the IP manually. Thanks for saving me time!